# jquery - multiple filters with and-or

Tags: jquery, filter

Say I have this:

```
<div class="red square">...</div>
<div class="white square">...</div>
<div class="blue square">...</div>

<div class="red triangle">...</div>
<div class="white triangle">...</div>
<div class="blue triangle">...</div>

<div class="red circle">...</div>
<div class="white circle">...</div>
<div class="blue circle">...</div>
```

How to select (red OR white) AND (circle OR square)?

This seems to work:

```
  $('div').filter('.red,.white').filter('.circle,.square').addClass('select');
```

But what if filters are variable (stored in object), perhaps only a choice of color, a single shape or with additional groups like size, ex:

```
filters = {color:".red,.blue", shape:".circle,.square"};
// or
filters = {color:".white", size:".medium,.small"};

 $('div').filter(filters[color]).filter(filters[shape]).filter(filters[size]).addClass('select');
// This won't work when one of the object key is absent.
```

Comment: Can you add final op as well in your question ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what 'final op' refers to.

Comment: I mean to say final output which you need .

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using an object comprised of keyword arrays (groups) and then using a filter to check if at least one keyword matches from each group.